# Boostrap carousel issues on ASP.Net Razor Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I am having a fair few issues using ASP.Net MVC 5 + Twitter Bootstrap 3.

Styling, that works, no issues - but the carousel I put in does not cycle, nor does it respond to the next/prev arrows or the navigation buttons.

I even gave in and pulled a carousel example from an article: ([Bootstrap Carousel Tutorial](http://bootstrapbay.com/blog/bootstrap-3-carousel-tutorial/) to rule out errors in my code.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css") <!-- this is the bundle name -->
    @Scripts.Render("~/Content/bundles/modernizr")      

</head>
<body>

   <!--------------------------- Carousel ------------------------------->


   ( Exact code from http://bootstrapbay.com/blog/bootstrap-3-carousel-tutorial/ )


   <!-------------------------------------------------------------------->

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>


    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

But It doesn't work, as described at the start. Any clues? [I don't want to clutter up the question with my Site.less or BundleConfig code - but if you need it, ask.]

( for the record I also tried

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/Scripts/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/Scripts/respond.js"></script>
```

rather than bundling - but same result...)

Comment: Check the developer tools of your browser and ensure that 1) the necessary Bootstrap JS is actually loading and 2) that there are no JS errors on page. If the bundler can't locate a script, it silently skips it, and even referencing it directly doesn't mean it's not just responding as a 404. Also, if there's any errors with any of your other scripts, that can sometimes block further processing of JS.

Comment: Ah brilliant, that put me on the right track - I'd had a reorg and moved the the files/renamed the bundle and hadn't updated the call. (should have been "~/Content/bundles/jquery" )

Answer (score 0):

Once pointed to look in the right direction I found that I moved the the files/renamed the bundle and hadn't updated the call.

instead of

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```

I should have had

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Content/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/Content/bundles/bootstrap")
```

to match the bundle config

```
var jqueryBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/Content/bundles/jquery");
...
var bootstrapBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/Content/bundles/bootstrap");
```